# Textual representation of attributes

Tags: undertow

Looking Undertown documentation at [Predicates, Attributes and Handlers](http://undertow.io/documentation/core/predicates-attributes-handlers.html) it seems that there is a textual representation for attributes that can be acceded some way like:

Hello %u the request method is %m  (example extracted from documentation where %u is remote user and %m is method).

My intention is to use them to log request time or log other tracing/debugging methods.

How can I use them? Is there any provided handler that can log strings with interpolated attributes?

Comment: I'm also looking for help regarding Undertow's handlers ([my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923989/redirect-http-to-https-in-undertow)). Documentation is quite obscure at this point.